# Overlapping linear regressions

Tags: regression, linear, overlapping-data

I have observations x,y. I am trying to learn a linear model for y against x. The local slope of the relationship maybe a function of y itself, and the nature of that relationship isn't clear.

To simplify the problem, I fit several linear models over overlapping subsets of my input data. I basically create subsets for some 'levels' or ranges of y (and take the corresponding x's), and build linear models over those subsets. For instance one subset could be all values of y s.t 10 < y < 15, another one could be an overlapping y s.t.    13 < y < 18 etc. In this process I have say 15 overlapping subsets of the original data, and I fit 15 linear models. My question is if this approach is robust? I can't seem to think why anyone may not do it, but I am not sure of the autocorrelation implication. I mean each linear model is dependent on the one next to it, since the input data has high overlap. The only reason I do that is because I want to be able to generate a lot of models as opposed to a few. Imagine that I had say 60 data points, and I wanted to make sure that I have atleast 20 data points per sample, I will only have 60/20 = 3 non overlapping samples. If I chose to go the overlapping route, I can have many more.

Comment: Consider looking into quantile regression, where the response is $\left\{y | P(Y < y | X) = q\right\}$ for some percentile $q$, rather than $E(Y|X)$.

Comment: I am not sure how that helps Andrew, maybe I am missing something. The whole reason I do the overlap is to generate many potential models. I could do a nonoveralp, but given that I have say only 60 points, I can only generate 3 models (say I want each model to have 20 points). With the overlap I can do many more, the question is if I it is robust?

Comment: But why do you want many models?

Comment: As I mentioned I expect the slopes to change with the quantiles of y, Actually Andrew I read up some stuff on quantile reg, and I now do see that it solves my problem. Would you be kind enough to explain how that would compare against my chosen approach? Many thanks!

Comment: The method isn't very robust, but something similar can be robustified. The basic idea is 'local regression" and common (somewhat robust) version of it for this is variously called LOESS or lowess. See wikipedia on [local regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression). There are a number of related ideas, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: I understand that that, I guess could you elaborate on why it isnt robust. LOESS is very similar to this idea also. Thanks a lot for  your help
!